# Finding non blank cell then in same row if another cell is blank then return value of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three columns. "Site ID" with a value, "Ready" with date and "Installation Completed" with date.

Now I want that I search whole column B for non-blank cell, if I found then it checks column C is blank, if column B is blank then write value of Column A in Column D where I am writing formula otherwise move to search for next non-blank value in Column B.

Hope you understand and help me with solution.

Comment: What would the argument be for column C "Installation Complete"? So if B is blank, is there a need to check c? If there is, would you want a notice like "Ready Date Missing" to appear in column d?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Site ID" is column A, "Ready" is B, and "Installation Complete" is C. You could use the following formula in column D and then copy it down as many rows as you need.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(ISBLANK(C2), A2,""))
```

This checks to see if cell B2 is blank and if so, does nothing else. If B2 has a value it will then check C2 for a value. If there is nothing in C2 it will show the value of A2.